# Saved layout not showing in new Map of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts

I am new to ArcGIS Pro and I am trying to use the same layout I used in Map 1 as in the figure below.

[image]

Now, I created another map (Map2), and I want to use the layout I saved ( I followed this [link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/overview/save-a-layout-file.htm) instructions to save layout3).

The next steps I took are the following

1. Insert Layout > Import Layout (The one I saved)

[image: This is what came out. As expected, its the same map from before with the first map I made]

2. Upon right clicking on the map frame in the table of contents, I selected my new map (Map 2).

[image]

3. Then, this happens. The map does not appear.

Is it because it is not linked with any of the other objects?

Also, the spatial reference system is the same as the first map..

[image]

For reference the new map I made is this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this such that I do not repeat everything and just use the layout I saved so that both figures are consistent?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear as to all the steps that you have performed but my suspicion is that you just need to insert two different Map Frames into your two different Layouts and have them both linked to the same Map.

To gain a clearer understanding of the process I suggest starting a new project, inserting a simple Map, inserting two Layouts, and then inserting a Map Frame using that same Map into each Layout.